# CSS issue: IE 6+ not display 'cursor' correctly - ninja help needed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, properties

IE 6+ is displaying the cursor as a text icon and not a mini-hand (pointer) as it should.

My **[Live Example](http://tinyurl.com/pgh521)** show how if you hover over a tab (All/Fore Sale/...), in IE - it displays a text-cursor but Firefox/etc it displays correctly as a "pointer".

This is applied to the `ul.tabbernav li a:hover` CSS property.

Any idea why IE is not displaying the cursor as a pointer when you hover over the tabs on my page?

Comment: have you tried applying the cursor attribute to the ul.tabbernav li a selector? Also, I would try setting a to be a block element.

Comment: how do I set it to be a "block element"?

Comment: add display:block on your a href

Comment: 'display:block" doesn't work.

Comment: @eulerfx, you found the problem - adding "cursor:pointer" to the 'ul.tabbernav li a' property fixed the problem

Comment: @eulerfx, if you post the cursor:pont to the other property as an answer - I'll mark is as the accepted answer for you to get the points.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer should always be used, however for really old IE there's a solution at the bottom of this page:

http://www.learnwebdesignonline.com/css-tutorials/cursor-hand-pointer.htm

Comment: I'm only concerned about having this working in IE 6 and above. I've linked to a live example in my original post now.

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor: pointer;
```

This works in IE 6+, Firefox & Chrome for me.

Comment: @presleyster, see my live example now in the updated original post. This does not work in IE for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the site you referenced and my own testing

```
cursor: pointer
```

works in IE6-8, Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.

As the site indicates

> By changing the value of the cursor
>   declaration you can assign cursor
>   styles to various HTML elements.
>   Although in theory this is great
>   functionality, it's very easy to
>   confuse your users by defining
>   inappropriate cursor styles. Please be
>   very careful; in general the browser
>   defaults work fine, and besides
>   they're what the user expects.

Tread lightly.

Comment: @ahsteele, that's what's strange ... see my Live Example site in the original post. It doesn't appear to be working with IE 6+

Answer (score 0):

Use both. `cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;` or `cursor: hand, pointer;` Can't remember now which one worked fine for me when doing clickable tables...

EDIT:

Apparently there's a specific order to get it working cross-browser:

`cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;`

Just tested it in IE8, Firefox, Safari and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your not getting the pointer because a href isn't getting set on the for sale, for rent and apartments <a> tags. It works on the All tab where the href is set to javascript:void(null);

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with trying to link a div (you probably already know that) thus switching it to an a tag would remove the problem. Then have javascript catch the click and return false thus no page reload?

*Also you really should pick up a js framework. Thats a lot of js that could be reduced using jQuery, mootools or whatever.*

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `cursor:pointer` to the `ul.tabbernav li a` resolved the problem, per eulerfx advice.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>

.element {cursor: pointer; }

</style>

<!-- the following as an example -->
<!--[if lte ie7]>

<style>

.element {cursor: hand; }

</style>

<![endif]-->
```

Covers all the bases, with only IE (less-than, or equal-to) 7 picking up the latter conditionally-commented style rules (though I think IE6+ understands `cursor: pointer`, but I'm not sure).

Comment: IE6 onward support cursor: pointer. IE < 6 doesn't support conditional comments.

Comment: @ricebowl, I only care that if IE 6 and above display the mini-hand because it is a link. See my live example web site. I've included the link in my updated original post

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to write the, since edited-in, comment regarding it being only an example, and the parenthesis was unfinished. I rushed; ah well...more haste, less speed...

Comment: @David Dorward - Conditional comments were added in IE5. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx